# Trigger to prevent updates but allow inserts

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

Can SQL Server triggers prevent updating records and allow inserting new records?

Thanks,
Przemek

Comment: restricting based on permissions is best.  It can be done with triggers, but there is an overhead.  Could you please explain your scenario in more detail, maybe there is a better way to accomplish what you want.

Comment: I've got a Customers table (Id, Name, City, ValidFrom, ValidTo). To keep track of changes I want to allow changes by adding new records, not updating current.

Comment: i see, so if someone wants to issue an update, what exactly are you expecting to happen?  Do you want an error thrown?  Do you want to replace the update with an update?

Comment: The problem seems to be a bit more complicated that I expected - I've created new thread to cover it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31219607/trigger-to-block-some-updates-and-allow-inserts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prevent update on table, you can use "INSTEAD OF UPDATE" Trriger
you can check this note "https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258254%28SQL.80%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396"

Comment: Thanks. Mohamed. Question is: how can I allow inserts in such a trigger?

Comment: you can allow insert using normal permission  "Grant" and control updates using this trigger

Comment: I need more clarification about your case so i can get a better solution for you

Comment: The problem seems to be a bit more complicated that I expected - I've created new thread to cover it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31219607/trigger-to-block-some-updates-and-allow-inserts

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't this be accomplished by creating a SQL Server user that has INSERT access on the destination tables but not UPDATE access? Create a new user with no permissions, then:

```
GRANT INSERT ON [blah] TO [user]
```

I admit, my knowledge of SQL Server triggers is limited, but this seems like it would work.

Comment: I'd like to display individual error information so preferebly trigger.

Comment: Permissions can control direct table access by non-privileged users but will not prevent updates via stored procedures, assuming the ownership chain is unbroken.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on `INSTEAD OF UPDATE`, this trigger will fire for `UPDATE` commands. `INSERT` and `DELETE` commands work as usual; if you wanted to intercept either of those you'd use an `INSTEAD OF INSERT` or `INSTEAD OF DELETE` trigger.

The full solution goes something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER myTable_IO_Upd ON myTable INSTEAD OF UPDATE AS
BEGIN
  RAISERROR('myTable does not allow UPDATE queries.', 18, 0);
END;
GO
```

More information on `RAISERROR` is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx). Basically the second argument (18) is the severity, with 18 being the highest severity allowed for user-defined exceptions. The third argument (0) is the "state", which you don't normally need, hence the zero.

One more example: if you wanted to prevent `UPDATE` *and* `DELETE`, you'd use something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER myTable_IO_Upd ON myTable INSTEAD OF UPDATE, DELETE AS
BEGIN
  RAISERROR('myTable does not allow UPDATE or DELETE queries.', 18, 0);
END;
GO
```

Comment: The problem seems to be a bit more complicated that I expected - I've created new thread to cover it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31219607/trigger-to-block-some-updates-and-allow-inserts